# NodeJS, RSA, is this secure?

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, rsa

Is this a secure way of encrypting with a public key and decrypting with the private?

If not, what do I need to add?  A pass of AES or similar?

```
var ursa = require('ursa');
var fs = require('fs');

// create a pair of keys (a private key contains both keys...)
var keys = ursa.generatePrivateKey();
console.log('keys:', keys);

// reconstitute the private key from a base64 encoding
var privPem = keys.toPrivatePem('base64');
console.log('privPem:', privPem);

var priv = ursa.createPrivateKey(privPem, '', 'base64');

// make a public key, to be used for encryption
var pubPem = keys.toPublicPem('base64');
console.log('pubPem:', pubPem);

var pub = ursa.createPublicKey(pubPem, 'base64');

// encrypt, with the public key, then decrypt with the private
var data = new Buffer('hello world');
console.log('data:', data);

var enc = pub.encrypt(data);
console.log('enc:', enc);

var unenc = priv.decrypt(enc);
console.log('unenc:', unenc);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this API, but typically you'd use some sort of padding with RSA. Without padding, the algorithm is known as "textbook RSA" and is insecure. Also, asymmetric encryption algorithms are extremely slow compared to symmetric algorithms and cannot be used for bulk data encryption (instead, you'd encrypt the symmetric key with RSA and then encrypt the data itself with the symmetric algorithm).

Comment: @ntoskrnl thanks, ursa defaults to RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING - can I assume this makes it not "textbook RSA" and therefore secure?

Comment: You said "decrypt with the public" in your code comment :>

Comment: OAEP is secure when implemented correctly. The commonly uses PKCS#1v1.5 encryption padding is not

Comment: @CodesInChaos what padding should I use?  Ursa says: "If no padding mode is specified, the default, and recommended, mode is `ursa.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING`. The mode `ursa.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING` is also supported."

Comment: OAEP is secure when implemented correctly. The commonly uses PKCS#1v1.5 encryption padding is not – CodesInChaos 46 mins ago

Comment: @ntoskrnl The library is called ursa (`var ursa = require('ursa');`), so a quick look up scored the pretty safe OAEP padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks secure, but if you want to encrypt strings you should normally use hybrid encryption. In that case you should indeed use AES. It is highly advisable to use some kind of message authentication as well if you use AES, especially if padding oracles could apply.

What's completely missing from your code is of course a method of trusting the public key. You generate the key pair in the code, but that is something that should not be performed frequently. Key management is one of the most important parts of cryptography.

Furthermore, this library looks like a one man show. Even if SLaks has contributed, you should be extremely wary of those kind of projects. For instance, the SJCL libraries had some huge holes in them and there have been some serious issues found within RNCrypt as well. Furthermore, these kind of projects easily end up without maintainer.

Documentation of the library is rather sparse as well. E.g. I presume that the `generatePrivateKey()` creates a key *pair* with a size of 2048 by default, but there is no way of checking that except for a code review or (indeed) testing the output. I don't presume it defaults to 512 bits, but with just the API doc, I cannot be sure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Generating the key pair was just to have all the code in one file - that's why I 'export' it to `privPem` and 'import' it later.  The API docs say 2048 is default.  https://github.com/Obvious/ursa#ursagenerateprivatekeymodulusbits-exponent  Thanks for your pointer to using a MAC.

Comment: The data I'm dealing with is typically < 100 bytes, hence not *requiring* AES.

Comment: Information on how to (public key) encrypt data (for storage in a file or database) seems very rare.  Encrypted communication is very well documented.  Why the difference?

Comment: Many databases, middleware and applications make assumptions on how they store data. It may not be easy to add encryption to that. It is often not possible to convert a value to encrypted form (field size, field type issues) Sometimes the database itself already performs some (rudamentary) form of encryption. Often the security is put on a different level: access conditions and encryption of entire database. Protecting files is rather well documented if you know where to look. PGP and CMS are well known formats and there are many disk, partition and file-system encryption mechanisms out there.